# How to get file path dynamically?

Tags: java, io

I write an application that load other classes from other folder like so :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String rootPath = null;
    rootPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    //System.out.println(rootPath);

    File operatorFile = new File(rootPath + "Business\\");
    URL operatorFilePath = operatorFile.toURL();
    URL[] operatorFilePaths = new URL[]{operatorFilePath};
    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(operatorFilePaths);

    // Plus , Minus,Multiply,Divide are classes in Business folder
    Class[] operatorClass = new Class[]{ cl.loadClass("Plus"), cl.loadClass("Minus"),cl.loadClass("Multiply") , cl.loadClass("Divide")
};
```

I Want Dynamically get the Business folder path(My main class is in MyFolder).
Both MyFolder and Business folders are in drive D:\  .
But this app dose not work because I think below statement dose not correct :

```
File operatorFile = new File(rootPath + "Business\\");
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: User.dir will return the "current executing context" or the directory from which your program is been executed

Comment: by using `"\\"` you make your code windows only. Use `File.separator`

Comment: Root path does not have \\ or /. Add file separator in this line. File operatorFile = new File(rootPath + File.seperator+ "Business"+File.seperator);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you Have to Remeber Some Points .

- Where you Home Drive Pointed :`System.getProperty("user.home");`//Either C or  D whatever .

**or :**

```
 rootPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"Business";
```

**or**

```
  String  rootPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"D"+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"MyFolder";
  rootPath=rootPath.replaceAll("MyFolder", "");//Remove MyFolder from URL
  rootPath=rootPath+"Business";//Add Business on URL
   System.out.println(""+rootPath);//Print File Path
```

that will Return your Home Directory With Business Folder

Comment: @ Anand Dwivedi Sorry I have a question  . above statment returns : D:\Myfolder But I just want D:\   .Is there anyway to get just D:\ becouse I need D:\Business

Comment: @marzie: can u plz tell me the full path that u want . so i can update code according to that

Comment: @ Anand Dwivedi My main Program is in D:\MyFolder I want Use some compiled code from D:\Business folder  . Now I want D:\Business But above statment give D:\MyFoder\Business

Comment: That meanse D:\MyFoder is your home directory right

Comment: @ Anand Dwivedi Yes I run the program form D:\MyFolder and it is my home directory But Business folder is in D:\Business

Comment: Check my updated Code . i remove MyFolder from URL and add Business . hope this will help